# Dialogflow API V2 largeImage for MediaObject not working

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I recently switched from the V1 to V2 for dialogflow and I'm updating my webhook.

I use mediaObjects with large Images in my agent as a personal taste.
Unfortunately I can't seem to make it work for the V2.
My current code for the media object is this:

```
 conv.ask(new MediaObject({
          name: 'Name',
          largeImage: new Image({
              url: 'https://[...].jpg',
              alt: 'alternative'
          }),
          url: 'https://[...].mp3',
          description: 'description'
}));
```

As you can see, I used the largeImage field, as I found it in the JSON section of [Google's example](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) . As the documentation is inexistant, I'm checking the node.js library for information and I verified that the largeImage field extends the Image interface so it should be correct.

It works when I switch largeImage for Icon but I don't like it.

My JSON response is like this:

```
"payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "text"
            }
          },
          {
            "mediaResponse": {
              "mediaType": "AUDIO",
              "mediaObjects": [
                {
                  "contentUrl": "https://[...].mp3",
                  "description": "description",
                  "name": "name"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": [
          {
            "title": "Not yet implemented"
          }
        ]
      },
      "userStorage": "{\"data\":{}}"
    }
  }
```

For some reason the largeImage field doesn't appear in my JSON but there isn't any error appearing anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the APIs in JSON do not match the Node.js parameters. For example, `largeImage` in JSON is actually [`image`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/efe2501301b428311cb0ed2cb1bae20ec919b011/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/response/media.ts#L42) in the [`MediaObjectOptions`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/interfaces/conversation_response.mediaobjectoptions.html) definition.

Comment: it works! Thank you ! I hope they will be able to put the same documentation as the V1 soon. (I have a dead link for MediaObjectOptions by the way)